# Javascript: Pause while a condition is true

Tags: javascript

I am interfacing with a third party SDK in my javascript code. I make func1 and func2. Func1 is wired to a "onFunc1" event where I keep track of a flag. When the flag is false, I try to call Func2. My objective is to issue Func1, wait until it finishes(the only way I know it finishes is when onFunc1 event is fired) and then, issue Func2. This is how my code is:

```
var _connected = false;
var _customWindow = CustomWindow.initialize();
_customWindow.on('Func1', function(){ window._connected = false; });

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
function goToNextWindow(){
    try{
      _customWindow.Func1();
    } catch(err){console.log('error calling Func1');}


    console.log('wait for Func1 to finish');
    while(window._connected === true){ 
        (async () => {
            await delay(300);
        })();

    }
    console.log('Func1 execution is done');
    if(window._connected === false){_customWindow.Func2();}

}
function button_click(){
    goToNextWindow();
}
```

I'm trying to make sure that Func1 is done executing before I issue the Func2 call. Is this a correct way of accomplishing my task? Can this be simplified?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just call `_customWindow.Func2()` inside the listener for `Func1`?

Comment: @code: Func1 is called at different places. And Func2 need not follow it.

Comment: tell us more about `onFunc1` event why can't you use that?

Comment: @ITgoldman: the SDK triggers onFunc1 if it encounters an error. I cannot differentiate between my Func1 call and the SDK's Func1 call.

Comment: Where do you call `goToNextWindow`?

Comment: @caTS: I have a button click event that calls the goToNextWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a promise that will resolve when you set `window._connected` to `false`. Then you can wait for that promise to resolve in your function:

```
let _connected = false;
let _customWindow = CustomWindow.initialize();

const waitToBeFalse = new Promise((resolve) => {
    _customWindow.on('Func1', function(){
        window._connected = false;
        resolve();
    });
});

async function goToNextWindow(){
    try{
      _customWindow.Func1();
    } catch(err){console.log('error calling Func1');}

    console.log('wait for Func1 to finish');
    
    await waitToBeFalse;

    if(window._connected === false){_customWindow.Func2();}
}
```

Comment: This solution gave me an idea to implement a state machine in JavaScript using xState to go into a wait state for a time period and get the connection status. Thank you.